# update column names systematically in SQL

Tags: sql

I have several tables with the same column names from 1 to 55. I want to update them systematically. Such as q1 to q55 or s1 to s55. What can I do to make it happen by using SQL? Your advice will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What RDMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, ....?

Comment: out of curiosity what is the reason you need to do this?

Comment: I used SQL server. I want to join several tables into a big one, but the primary keys shared the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Most databases support the following:

```
alter table <tablename> rename column <dolname> to <newname>
```

I would generate a script to do this in Excel and then run it.

SQL Server does not support this syntax.  Instead, you can use the command `sp_rename`.  Once again, I would set up the statements in Excel to create them in bulk.